# Can i not load iframes until page has loaded?

Tags: iframe, onload

I'm looking for a way to speed up a tumblr page.
Because there are a lot of iframes loaded when you open the main page the page loads really slow. Is there a way that I can disable the load of the iframes until the page has been loaded entirely?

Thanks so much

Comment: You can assign its src attribute after page was loaded. But I'm unsure that iframes affects top page loading.

Comment: Yeah for sure, If I look into the chrome developer tool the iframes are the things that slowing the page down. Especially embeds like youtube and vimeo etc..